# Como actualizar un registro con imágenes

Tags: php, update, img

Estoy creando un CRUD para la tabla usuarios con php y mysql.

Tengo que actualizar el registro de un usuario y este tiene un campo foto.
En la base de datos guardo el nombre y en una carpeta llamada "img" guardo las imagenes

Quiero saber como puedo eliminar la foto anterior antes de guardar la nueva en caso de que sea diferente?

Comment: Para poder ayudarte tienes que mostrar como guardaste la foto en la DB. Si la guardaste directamente en la tabla como un (stream), no tendrias que modificar nada pero si solamente guardaste la ruta en la bd y subiste la foto al servidor, simplemente tendrias que borrar la foto (solo en caso de que el usuario selecciono otra)  con algo como la funcion unlink() y luego actualizar la nueva ruta en la bd.